# Reference request: law of large numbers

Tags: references, law-of-large-numbers

I am writing a paper, and I need to cite the law of large numbers.

Precisely, I want to use the statement that if $\{x_{1},...,x_{n}\}$ are independent random samples generated from a distribution with expectation $\mu $, then 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_{i}}{n} = \mu.
$$

Which is the standard reference for this theorem?

Comment: That there should be *a* standard reference is questionable.  That there are myriad accessible references is evident from a Web search for [weak law of large numbers](https://www.google.com/search?q=weak+law+of+large+numbers)

Comment: Which law of large numbers? Strong or weak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my reference statistical book, this theorem is listed on page 200 as Theorem 4.3.1 (Strong law of large numbers). [Probability & Statistics - The Science of Uncertainty, M.J. Evans & J.S.Rosenthal, W.H.Freeman and Company, New York, 2004].

For a more extensive proof of the 'Strong law of large numbers', see for example the reference work:
J.S. Rosenthal. A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory
2nd Edition, World Scientific, 2006.